# Xamarin iOS - Why Can't I Iterate or Fetch by Index on an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, nsarray

I am trying to either iterate over an NSArray in Xamarin, or fetch items by index as follows :

```
  try
    {  
        NSData value = (NSData)NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults["accounts"];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiver = new NSKeyedUnarchiver(value);

        NSArray valuesDictionary = (NSArray)NSKeyedUnarchiver.UnarchiveObject(value);

        foreach (var x in valuesDictionary)
        {

        }


        if (valuesDictionary != null)
        {
            var accountList = new List<Account>();

            int numberOfOrgs = (int)valuesDictionary.Count;

            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfOrgs; x++)
            {
                var org = valuesDictionary[x];
            }
        }
```

However the compiler throws errors both for the iteration and the indexing.

```
   foreach (var x in valuesDictionary)
    {

    }
```

errors with "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'NSArray' because 'NSArray' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

and

`var org = valuesDictionary[x];`

errors with "Cannot apply indexing to a type of NSArray".

Can anyone suggest why this is ? In Objective C I think I'd be able to do both of these things.

Thanks !

Comment: To retrieve an object from an NSArray in Xamarin you can use the `NSArray.ValueAt` method, as for using the C# `foreach`, there is no C# enumerator, you can use a `for` loop using the `NSArray.Count` property. NSArray are loose typed, so user beware :-)

Comment: Thanks - just for future travellers I found that you can use the Xamarin getItem<NSObject>(0) method on an NSArray which works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future that has this problem, although you can't index on an NSArray, you can use the Xamarin method of :

```
GetItem<type>(index)
```

e.g

```
myArray.GetItem<NSObject>(0).
```

Works like a charm :)